# c using a multi dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d

Using a 2D array for the first time for my university project.

im struggling on how to place a user entered value into a specific slot in the array.

what i do have is.

```
cout << "Enter Number of Groups" << endl;
cin >> DefinedGroups;

int user_groups[definedgroups] [2]

while (havent worked out the condition yet)
{
cout << " Enter Lower Range " << endl;
cin >> Lrange;
cout << " Enter Higher Range " << endl;
cin >> Hrange;
}
```

Anyone Know how I can enter the value from Lrange and Hrange into the array at like 0,1 and 1,1 and then increment the definedgroup by 1 each time. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your code uses Variable Length Arrays which are a GCC extension. This means your code is not portable.

Now to read into the elements in the array, you could simply do:

```
cout << " Enter Lower Range " << endl;
cin >> user_groups[i][0];
cout << " Enter Higher Range " << endl;
cin >> user_groups[i][1];
```

Assuming that `i` is an index into the array that you'll get when you figure out the while loop condition.

If you'd like to enlighten yourself, you could use a more idiomatic method:

```
int defined_groups;
std::cin >> defined_groups;
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> user_groups;
for (int i = 0; i < defined_groups; i++) {
  int lower_range, upper_range;
  if (cout << "Enter Lower Range " << endl &&
      std::cin >> lower_range &&
      cout << " Enter Higher Range " << endl &&
      std::cin >> upper_range) {
    user_groups.push_back(std::make_pair(lower_range, upper_range));
  }
}
```

Comment: @NikosC. That's not a problem, GCC has a C++ compiler as well (`g++`).

Comment: @H2CO3 (Aren't deleted comments fun? :-P) Note how the question is tagged C++ and not g++ though. So it has to be pointed out that the code is not valid, standard C++.

Comment: @NikosC. Ah, so you replied to someone who deleted his comment. Fine. Sorry for that, in this case.

Comment: thanks for that! im going to stay away from vectors as we get tested on this to ensure we understand our own code and not copied of the web! lol.